# How to configure Qt with Godot using Scons (in windows)

Tags: python, c++, qt, scons, godot

I want to use Qt with [SCons](http://scons.org/) so I can work with Godot in Qt. I appreciate if anyone could be more specific than the godot [manual](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/cpp/configuring_an_ide.html) about how to do that, especially about how to prepare the Build configuration and the Run configuration in Qt to work with SCons.

The  godot manual says that I should do the following:

- Click on Projects and open the Build tab.
- Delete the pre-defined make build step.
- Click Add Build Step -> Custom Process Step.
- Type scons in the Command field.
- Fill the field with your compilation options. (e.g.: p=x11
  target=debug -j 4)

when I type **p=x11 target=debug -j 4** in the Arguments for the Build steps, and **p=x11 target=debug -j 4 --clean** for the clean steps field and when I press the build project button I get the following message “Python has stopped working”. I’m using windows. How can I configure this for windows? (I have an hp 8770w, with processor 3920xm) 
The following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFH8bRcuHqg)  help me until minute 2:36

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean in your case? Can you show the error message that you get, if there is any? Also, if you are under Windows the specification "p=x11" is probably **not** what you need. Read up in the manual about how to compile the project under Windows in general. My guess is that you need different command-line options, these should be given in the manual somewhere.

Comment: when I press the build project button I get the following message “Python has stopped working” 
I don’t know which command-line options should I use. If I modify the p=x11, for p=windows, or p=x64, I get the same “Python has stopped working”.

Comment: Step 1: Make the build work on the command-line, the manual describes how to do that. Step 2: Configure the IDE (I guess it's QtCreator in your case) such that it creates the same command-line when building.

Comment: I installed scons in my computer and try to used with the instructions of the scons manual http://scons.org/doc/1.0.0/HTML/scons-user/c251.html however I get the following error **Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec 
ModuleNotFoundError: no module name encodings** 
I have not been able to solve this yet, but, I think I should not have to install SCons on my computer, rather I should use the SCons file that is in the godot folder (I download godot from https://github.com/godotengine/godot)

Comment: What exactly did you try to solve the "Fatal Python error"? Mainly which search terms did you use while trying to find a solution? Also, if you want to follow the steps in the video you mentioned above, you will **have to** install *SCons* and should ensure that it's working properly first. The steps in the video clearly select the "`scons`" executable to be run for building the project, instead of the default setting "`make`".

Comment: Sorry I don’t have much experiences with these programs. I think that in the video he is using the scons file that is in the Godot folder, that is because in the working directory he is using %{buildDir} and the buildDir =  /home/tyboroth/Git/godot, so **scons** is making the build in buildDir, right? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't have any experience with *QtCreator* or *Godot*. But the Godot manual lists *Python* and *SCons* as prerequisites for compiling under Windows. So you have to install both of those I'd figure, right? Can you run Python on the command-line? Can you run SCons on the command-line? You have to ensure these things first, before making the next step and hiding all this machinery behind an IDE....

Comment: Godot docs tell you explicitly here what you need to install to build: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html  Have you installed all those?

Comment: Many thanks bdbaddog and dirkbaechle. I didn’t know that I have to download the programs specified in http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html. I have done it now, but I have another problem. I’m Moving the question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643965/scons-compilation-error-with-visual-studio-2015